# One-way partial table synchronization for desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, synchronization

I'm a programmer, but I'm not experienced with databases, and this is my first post, if my post is not respecting any rules please point them out so I can improve them, thank you.

I have desktop application (.Net WPF application) using a local database (MS SQL).
I have also a central server containing a MS SQL server database
And a mobile app that needs access (read-only) to the data located in the central server.

Each client has the desktop application installed on their computer (from which all data is inserted/modified/deleted), and they also have the mobile app that should give them access (read-only) to the data located in the central server.

All clients share the same central database, and the same tables, but each client can only access specific rows that belong to them.

I'm trying to figure out how to synchronize the inserted/modified/deleted rows in the desktop database to the central database (only one-way synchronization).

I have done some research, and I found that there are several technologies that can be used, like Replication, CDC, software (Symmertricds...) or even programming it from ground up, but I'm still confused which one is the right one for this case.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, replication will not work in your case as SQL Server Express only supports being a subscriber and the way you described the sync requires each local database to be a publisher. You would have to upgrade to a paid version to use replication in the way you describe it.

Comment: @RossBush thank you, i didn't know that, would you direct me to an alternative.

Comment: First question: Do you need these updates as soon as they happen, or periodically throughout the day, or once daily, or less frequently?  Will you be updating based on one database action, one full transaction (say, saving a new PO, possibly including a new customer, new addresses, etc. as one transaction), based on aging, or based on some other criteria?

Comment: @LaughingVergile updates would be made after full transactions and preferably as soon as possible, say every 5min.